# Get Logged in UserName in view in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have got a `Log Out` button in my `_layout.cshtml`. I would like to show Logged In user name inside the logout button to see who logged in at the moment.

```
<a class="btn btn-sm" asp-action="" asp-controller="">Log Out( @ViewBag.LoggedInUserName )</a>
```

In my controller I used:

```
ViewBag.LoggedInUserName = userManager.GetUserName(HttpContext.User);
```

With this way, I need to declare ViewBag every single method in each controller. 
I am sure there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to pass it from controller method using `ViewBag`. You can simply do as follows:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<a class="btn btn-sm" asp-action="" asp-controller="">Log Out(@UserManager.GetUserName(User))</a>
```

Note: If you are extending `IdentityUser` with something like `ApplicationUser` then replace  `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser` as follows:

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a PartialView and place it in your shared _layout.cshtml.

```
<partial name="_LoginPartial" />
```

And in your PartialView you can ad something similar like the following code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route 
        returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" 
        id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" 
                 title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar- 
                    link">Logout</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Orvar. But Tanvir's answer is quicker.